# Case Match Scala

Tags: scala

We have this as an exam question (practice) and the answer is 1 and 6. I have no idea how this is the answer and stepping the program also didn't help. Could anyone explain why this is the answer and how to approach this question.

```
    var value1: Int = 4
    var value2: Int = 6

    value1 match {

      case 1 => value2 += 1

    case 2 => value2 -= 4

    case 3 => value1 = value2 * 2

    case 4 => value1 -= 3;

    case 5 => value2 += 1

    case _ => value1 = value2 + 1

    }

println("value1 = " + value1 + ", value2 = " + value2)
```

Comment: Do you know what a case statement does? Which part of this is confusing you?

Comment: Obviously `case 4 => value1 -= 3;` is selected. Semicolons are not necessary btw

Comment: I'm unsure why case 4 was selected

Comment: @user7724005 because `value1: Int = 4` and `value1 match`! Obviously, 4 matches 4!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you're confused about how the `match` works. Although it looks similar to a `switch` statement in some other languages, it's somewhat different.

In Scala, `case` expressions do not "fall through". Each case is evaluated independently, and its block is executed if the variable, `value1` in this case, matches the pattern. As soon as a block is executed, all other (potentially matching) cases are ignored.